# Javascript in a Included PHP File

Tags: php, javascript, include

I have a php file (a form) that includes javascript to check if all inputs are filled. When I view the php file directly the js works perfectly, but when I include the PHP file in another page the javascript no longer works.

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("topField").setAttribute("autocomplete","off");
    }

window.onload = function() {
    // get the form and its input elements
    var form = document.forms[0],
        inputs = form.elements;
    // if no autofocus, put the focus in the first field
    if (!Modernizr.input.autofocus) {
        inputs[0].focus();
    }
    // if required not supported, emulate it
    if (!Modernizr.input.required) {
        form.onsubmit = function() {
            var required = [], att, val;
            // loop through input elements looking for required
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                att = inputs[i].getAttribute('required');
                // if required, get the value and trim whitespace
                if (att != null) {
                    val = inputs[i].value;
                    // if the value is empty, add to required array
                    if (val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') == '') {
                        required.push(inputs[i].name);
                    }
                }
            }
            // show alert if required array contains any elements
            if (required.length > 0) {
                alert('The following fields are required: ' +
                    required.join(', '));
                // prevent the form from being submitted
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in the error console?

Comment: check your JS console for errors?

Comment: Do you include this in a php file on the same directory level? note the script path

Comment: You are using relative paths...it will be relative the the page being loaded, not the original page including it.

Comment: your problem is probably the src tag in you first script inclusion. Have you checked that when you include the file the modernizer.js is indeed in that path?

Comment: There's nothing in the error console. I even used an absolute path: "http://localhost/js/modernizr.js" and still nothing.

Comment: Are you assigning other functions using window.onload directly? You can only assign one function using this method. If you want to assign more, you need to chain it in some way.

Comment: @datasage I didn't know that you can only use one window.onload . The only two I was using were on this included php file (The code I posted above). I took the script from the first one out and still no luck.

Comment: @TKink are there any in the page you are trying to include this file in? If there are, they might override the onloads in this file. The one that is set last will be the only one called.

Comment: @datasage Yep that's it. I was using an window.onload in my header that was overriding it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation to anyone who finds this question later. In javascript you can only attach a single function to an event handler. If you want to attach more, you need to chain them. Pretty much all javascript framework/libraries has some sort of method to handle event chaining.

Javascript allows you to treat functions like variables. So you can assign an old onload function to a variable, then call it later within the new onload function.

If you are not using a framework, you can do something like this to handle event chaining.

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
```

You would call this with the following:

```
addLoadEvent(function(){
  // Some code here
});
```